# How to Show an image

Tags: react-native

I got a bunch of data from my database and I am mapping all of them, my image field is also part of that database and in that, I am storing the URL of that specific image link, but I am not able to map pictures cuz URI needs to be a string and the data I am getting is of type int, here is the code

**Code**

```
data.map((key)=>{
    return(
        <View>
            <Image style={styles.myImage} source={{
                uri:`${key.link}`
             }} />
        </View>
    )
  })
```

Comment: "uri needs to be string and the data I am getting is of type int". What do you mean by this can you share the data which your receiving

Comment: @Alpha i am getting the url of images that is stored in the database and it seems pretty fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **link** is correctly defined this should work :

```
source={{ uri: key.link }}
```

But make sur you have set width/height in your style

```
 style={{height: your_height, width:  your_width}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the image is coming in that link then you just have to pass a height and width for that image.

```
 <Image source={{
    uri:`${key.link}`
  }}
   style={{height:100, width:100}}
 />
```